# Custom control does not show on only iPhone 6 and iPhone 6s simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview

I am creating a custom control. 
When I run the program, the custom control does not show on iPhone 6 and iPhone 6s simulator. on iPhone 7, iPhone 7 plus, iPhone SE, etc. Everything works ok.

In my control, I put a `UIView` (`backView`) to draw a path on it and a `UIImageView` and a `UIButton` upon it. It is just something like a bar with single button.

Here is some related part of my source

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class ButtonBar: UIControl {

    // -- MARK: controls
    @IBOutlet weak var backView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var actionButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    // -- MARK: customize properties
    // some @IBInspectable properties here...

    // -- MARK: other properties
    weak var view: UIView!
    var backgroundLayer: CAShapeLayer!

    // -- MARK: init()s
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupSubViews()
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupSubViews()
    }

    // -- MARK: override functions
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        guard view != nil else {
            return
        }

        view.frame = bounds
        self.refresh()
    }

    // -- MARK: other functions
    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
        let clazz = type(of: self)
        let bundle = Bundle(for: clazz)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "\(clazz)", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        return view
    }

    func setupSubViews() {
        view = loadViewFromNib()
        view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight]
        self.addSubview(view)
        self.backgroundLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        self.backView.layer.addSublayer(self.backgroundLayer)
        self.refresh()
    }

    public func refresh() {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        // code to create the path...
        path.close()

        self.backgroundLayer.path = path.cgPath
        self.backgroundLayer.fillColor = self.barColor.cgColor
        self.backgroundLayer.strokeColor = self.borderColor.cgColor
        self.backgroundLayer.lineWidth = CGFloat(self.borderWidth)

        self.backView.layer.replaceSublayer(self.backgroundLayer, with: self.backgroundLayer)

        self.image.image = self.buttonImage

        self.buttonTopConstraint.constant = CGFloat(t - to)
    }
}
```

And I just drag a UIView into my storyboard and set its class as this custom control.

If I override the `draw(_:)` function and call `refresh()` function in it, it works on iPhone 6[s] simulators. But I know that is not a good practice since some performance problem.

Is there something wrong in my code or just a bug of iPhone 6[s] simulator?

== update ==
I send my project to others who using xcode 8.2 (I just upgraded it to 8.3.1), and he removed the bottom constraint and re-add it again with the same value. The problem fixed.

I received the project he send back to me and remove the constraint and then added it again. The problem is not reproduced. While I do the same to my original project, the problem remains.

Is this a bug of xcode?

Comment: In `self.buttonTopConstraint.constant = CGFloat(t - to)` what are `t` and `to`?

Comment: `t` and `to` are variables calculated from `bounds.height` and other properties. They are used to determine the position of my button. On other simulators it works well, so I believe they have the right value.